# Why do I catch IOException, when I use JGit library DiffFormatter?

Tags: java, git, diff, jgit

I want to check what files are exactly changed, using DiffEntries, but I catch IOException:

```
        try {
            Git git = Git.open(new File(System.getProperty("user.dir")));

            DiffFormatter df = new DiffFormatter(new ByteArrayOutputStream());
            df.setRepository(git.getRepository());

            List<DiffEntry> diffs = git.diff()/*.setOutputStream( System.out )*/.call();

            for(DiffEntry diff : diffs) {
                df.format(diff); //IOException here

                System.out.println(diff.getChangeType() + " " + diff.getNewPath());
            }
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Here is the stack trace:

```
org.eclipse.jgit.errors.MissingObjectException: Missing blob 74f1fb04c13074b809262b7ab7af1766cfe4bf95
    at org.eclipse.jgit.internal.storage.file.WindowCursor.open(WindowCursor.java:170)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.diff.ContentSource$ObjectReaderSource.open(ContentSource.java:145)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.diff.ContentSource$Pair.open(ContentSource.java:282)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.diff.DiffFormatter.open(DiffFormatter.java:1073)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.diff.DiffFormatter.createFormatResult(DiffFormatter.java:1001)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.diff.DiffFormatter.format(DiffFormatter.java:706)
    at com.plugin.engine.Main.main(Main.java:39)
```

Overall it's came to WindowsCurcor.java in JGit library:

```
/** {@inheritDoc} */
    @Override
    public ObjectLoader open(AnyObjectId objectId, int typeHint)
            throws MissingObjectException, IncorrectObjectTypeException,
            IOException {
        final ObjectLoader ldr = db.openObject(this, objectId);
        if (ldr == null) {
            if (typeHint == OBJ_ANY)
                throw new MissingObjectException(objectId.copy(),
                        JGitText.get().unknownObjectType2);
            throw new MissingObjectException(objectId.copy(), typeHint); //Exception thrown here
        }
        if (typeHint != OBJ_ANY && ldr.getType() != typeHint)
            throw new IncorrectObjectTypeException(objectId.copy(), typeHint);
        return ldr;
    }
```

How can I print file changes using JGit and why do I catch IOException?

Comment: What does the stack trace say? Are you sure there's a git repo in the user's home directory itself (as opposed to some subdirectory)?

Comment: @AndyTurner I've edited the question, thank you. Yes, I'm sure there's a git repo

Comment: Sounds like a broken Git repository. Does commandline "git diff" work fine here?

Comment: @centic yeah, it's work fine

Comment: If JGit fails on this repository while normal git works fine while doing the same operation would indicate a bug in JGit here.

Comment: Well, sounds very sad :C But thank you, will look for replacement